# Apache 2.4 Form + mod_authn_dbd + socache = 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: apache-2.4

I have been banging my head on the wall for a while, can someone please take a look at my conf file which is located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/website.conf. I am trying to secure members.website.com. I want people to login at website.com/login and cache the credentials. The site is secure; login and logout work correctly but none of the content will load. I just get the errors below. I appreciate any help.

Error I get in my browser:
**Method Not Allowed

The requested method GET is not allowed for the URL /index.php.**

Error in /var/log/httpd/error_log
**AH01811: the form-login-handler only supports the POST method for /index.php, referer: http://website.com/login/**

```
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "host=12.34.56.78 port=3306 user=db_username pass=db_PASSWORD dbname=db_database"
DBDMin  2
DBDKeep 4
DBDMax  10
DBDExptime 300

<VirtualHost *:80>
  DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
  DocumentRoot /var/www/members.website.com/public_html
  ServerName members.website.com
    <Directory />
        AllowOverride All
        Options FollowSymLinks
    </Directory>

    <Location />
        SetHandler form-login-handler
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://website.com/login"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://members.website.com"
        AuthFormProvider socache dbd
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT cryptpass FROM member_table WHERE username = %s AND siteid = 1"
        AuthType form
        AuthName website-login
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret1234
        AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location /login>
        SetHandler form-login-handler
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://website.com/login"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://members.website.com"
        AuthFormProvider socache dbd
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT cryptpass FROM member_table WHERE username = %s AND siteid = 1"
        AuthType form
        AuthName website-login
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret1234
        AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd
        Require valid-user
    </Location>

    <Location "/logout">
        SetHandler form-logout-handler
        AuthFormLogoutLocation "http://website.com/logged_out"
        Session On
        SessionMaxAge 1
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase dr41h85et4h89ewr4h9w8eh1et561jhe6541w4r1ywe
    </Location>

    <Directory "/var/www/members.website.com/public_html/administrator">
        AuthName "Member Admin Only"
        AuthType Basic
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 100.0.0.0/8
        Allow from 12.34.56.78
    </Directory>
```

Login Form HTML

```
<form method="POST" action="http://members.website.com">
Username: <input type="text" name="httpd_username" value="" /><br />
Password: <input type="password" name="httpd_password" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="login" value="Login" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be working now. Although I am not sure if this is optimized and I am not sure how to test that socache is working but I see the username in the logs and the errors have gone away. I modified the following sections:

```
    <Location />
        AuthType form
        AuthName website-login
        AuthFormProvider dbd socache
        Session On
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT cryptpass FROM member_table WHERE username = %s AND siteid = 1"
        SessionEnv On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
        Require valid-user
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://website.com/login"
    </Location>

    <Location /login>
        SetHandler form-login-handler
        AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "http://website.com/login"
        AuthFormLoginSuccessLocation "http://members.website.com"
        AuthFormProvider dbd
        AuthDBDUserPWQuery "SELECT cryptpass FROM member_table WHERE username = %s AND siteid = 1"
        AuthType form
        AuthName website-login
        Session On
        SessionCookieName session path=/
        SessionCryptoPassphrase secret
        AuthnCacheProvideFor dbd socache
        Require valid-user
    </Location>
```

Comment: I am now seeing something interesting in my logs. I am not sure if it is due to the above configuration change or coincidence hack attempt.

::1 - - [19/Oct/2015:13:45:50 -0700] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 - "-" "Apache/2.4.16 (Amazon) OpenSSL/1.0.1k-fips PHP/5.6.13 (internal dummy connection)"